# Count number of rows that a value stored in a list occurs in

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

There is a DataFrame `df` that holds data in list of strings:

```
>> df
     words
0  [a,b,c]
1      [a]
2  [x,c,c]
3      [a]
...
```

I want to count the number of rows that each value in `words` occurs in. For example:

```
a: 3
b: 1
c: 2
x: 1
```

I get a list of all unique words in the DataFrame using:

```
>> from collections import OrderedDict #using OrderedDict to keep word order
>> l = []
>> df.words.apply(lambda x: l.append(x)) #add list of words to a list
>> l = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys([j for i in l for j in i])) #merge list of lists and remove duplicates
>> print(l)
[a,b,c,x]
```

From here I go through the list `l` and checking each row of `df` if the word exists, and then sum the Bool value for each word.

```
data = []
for w in l:
  tmp = []
  df.words.apply(lambda x: tmp.append(w in x))
  data.append(sum(tmp))
```

I can then create a dictionary of words and their count. This is, however, very inefficient, as it takes a long time (70,000+ words and 50,000+ rows). Is there a faster way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html)

```
df['words'].explode().values_counts(sort=False)
```

One more alternative is using [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) with [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
counts = Counter(chain.from_iterable(df['words']))
pd.Series(counts)
a    3
b    1
c    3
x    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: `df['words'].explode().values_counts(sort=False)`

Answer (score 0):

Convert each list to a set, then back to list. Combine them using itertools and then run a collections.Counter on it to get the dictionary.

```
#if data is your list of lists or dataframe
import itertools
import collections

data = [list(set(i)) for i in data]
newData = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(data))
#chain makes an iterator that returns elements from the first iterable until it is 
#exhausted, then proceeds to the next iterable, until all of the iterables are 
#exhausted.
dictVal = collections.Counter(newData)
```